# How to invoke a Spring Security Provider?

Tags: java, spring, grails

I have a web app that I am migrating to Grails 3.3.9 (from Grails 2.3.11). The current version of the application utilizes Spring Security LDAP for authentication (user sees login form when they try to access site and they type in username and password). The newer version of the application will utilize the Spring Security SAML plugin for authentication (commonly referred to as Single Sign On).

I have the Single Sign On (SSO) working however the SSO Login Page is only accessible when a user is at our office (has a certain IP address). In the cases where the user is not at our office (has an IP address not in our network). I would like the user to have the option to login with the Spring Security LDAP login form.

I'm sort of lost how to do it though. From the info I've gathered I need to define my security provider in `application.groovy`(I've used the default Spring Security providers as they seem to do the job individually). What I don't understand though is how do I tell Grails which of the two login methods to use per user. In my instance it would be checking the IP address of the user (which I already have the code for), but how do I then say, for example:

```
if(ipAddress matches internalIPRange) use samlAuthenticationProvider
else{use ldapAuthProvider}
```

Here is the provider set up in `application.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['samlAuthenticationProvider', 'ldapAuthProvider', 'daoAuthenticationProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider']
```

Also I don't know how to actually call the provider manually (something like `provider.invoke()` if I had to guess).

Comment: I think you should introduce a `filter` as per https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#filters and let it do the IP check. If the IP is in range redirect to SAML login, or LDAP otherwise

Comment: @injecteer How do I actually call the SAML and LDAP logins though?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be fairly easy to implement.

You extend the [ExceptionTranslationFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java)  like so:

```
class IpAwareExceptionTranslationFilter extends ExceptionTranslationFilter {

  AuthenticationEntryPoint ldapAuthenticationEntryPoint

  @Override
  void sendStartAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
        AuthenticationException reason) throws ServletException, IOException {
      SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication = null
      requestCache.saveRequest request, response
      logger.debug 'Calling Authentication entry point.'
      if( isAllowedIpAddress( request ) )
        authenticationEntryPoint.commence request, response, reason // default SAML
      else
        ldapAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence request, response, reason // LDAP
  }
}
```

Then you declare your filter as a `bean` in `resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {

  exceptionTranslationFilter( IpAwareExceptionTranslationFilter ){
    authenticationEntryPoint = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint( '/saml/login' )
    ldapAuthenticationEntryPoint = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint( '/ldap/login' )
  }

}
```

and it should replace the default `exceptionTranslationFilter` in the filter chain.